# Some clarifications are needed about the grammar of Elliptical Structure

Tags: ellipsis, formal-language

As far as I know, one application of elliptical structure is the omission from a clause one or more elements which has been repeated in previous clauses. However, I do not know whether there exists some specific general rule stating how and when to apply this structure.

Let me be more specific:

> 1. Is it correct to say that one can *always* omit any word which has been repeated before?
> 2. Is this structure optional (I have read somewhere that sometimes it is obligatory, for example with cases of comparative deletion (for example, the sentence “More students were in the class today than were there yesterday”), but I also have read somewhere that the omitted words can be added without producing an ungrammatical structure)?

I want to emphasize that I want to know the answer to my question for **formal English** used in academic writing.

---

### Updated

After pondering the useful comments, I conclude that one should not consider any omission of words as ellipsis. In fact, ellipsis is the omission of elements which are understood in the context of the remaining elements and recoverable from the linguistic context. So examples such as “*seeing more examples and gaining <sub>more</sub> experience*” and “*making more effort and reading <sub>more</sub> grammar textbooks*” cannot be considered as elliptical structures since the second *more* is not recoverable from the linguistic context (We would have two sentences with different meaning before and after the omission of the second *more*).

So I think the first question should be rephrased as follows.

> 1’. Which repeated elements of a sentence can be omitted in order to get an elliptical structure?

Comment: In your example, you've performed one repetition *(**were**)*, and one "substitution" *(**there = in the class**)*. You can validly omit ***both*** (and most people usually would), but it's certainly not valid to delete just the verb. *More students were in the class today than there yesterday* looks completely invalid to me, but I wouldn't know how to describe the problem in terms of "syntax violation".

Comment: I'm also unsure whether it's meaningful to say that your example "deletes" the predictable repeated *subject* *(**students**)* of the potentially deletable verb ***were***. But on reflection, the example given in previous comment is perfectly grammatical. It's just stylistically appalling.

Comment: Few things are *always* in English – especially so with ellipsis, and hence I think the answer is *no, a general rule doesn't exist*. I would think where ellipsis is optional *and felicitous*, however, formal English would permit dispensing with it, while informal, everyday English favors as much ellipsis as possible, so long as the meaning gets across.

Comment: *"Omitted words can be added without producing an ungrammatical structure.*" Adding back omitted words can never be ungrammatical. However, doing so may sound stilted and stylistically awkward in some cases. As in other comments, it's impossible to come up with any kind of general rule. What's idiomatic is simply too broad and, sometimes, illogical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your help. From your comment I conclude that one cannot find a general rule for using elliptical structure and should learn this skill only by seeing more examples and gaining more experience (I think the the second “*more*” cannot be omitted here, so the answer to the first question in the original post must be “No”). Am I right?

Comment: @userr2684291 Thank you for your help. From your comment I conclude that one cannot find a general rule for using elliptical structure and should learn this skill only by seeing more examples and gaining more experience (I think the the second “*more*” cannot be omitted here, so the answer to the first question in the original post must be “No”). Am I right?

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for your help. From your comment I conclude that one cannot find a general rule for using elliptical structure and should learn this skill only by seeing more examples and gaining more experience (I think the the second “*more*” cannot be omitted here, so the answer to the first question in the original post must be “No”). Am I right?

Comment: @JasonBassford From your comment I conclude that your answer to the second question is “Yes” (i.e., using elliptical structure is optional), so you are disagree with the point in my original post that sometimes elliptical structure is obligatory (for example, in the sentence “*More students were in the class today than were there yesterday*”)?

Comment: You say you think the second instance of "more" in *by seeing more examples and gaining more experience*, which is perfectly true. Well, you *can* omit it - but if you do, native speakers won't assume the first instance also applies to "experience". Which in practice makes no real difference to the meaning in that *exact* example. But it would in, say, *making more effort and reading [more] grammar textbooks*, where presence / absence of the second instance strongly implies you have / haven't already read at least *some* grammar textbooks.

Comment: ...I don't know how to articulate the relevant "rule" forcing the above distinction, but I assume that's mostly because I'm a native speaker, so I just "know" that those two different meanings entirely turn on whether "more" is repeated or not. Since you're *not* a native speaker, the fact that *you* can make the same distinction might imply you have actually learned some relevant rule...

Comment: ...If you can think that one through, perhaps you can explain exactly what rule you *do* know (that enables you to get *that* one right), and present us with a different example where you're *not* sure how to decide. Then maybe I (or someone else here) will be able to give you more help! :)

Comment: I've removed the first paragraph. This was a preamble that was not central to the question asked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... is it because of the change of verb? "Making more ... reading more" is required, whereas you could say "making more cakes and buns", but not "making more cakes and mixing dough" and have "more" be inferred by the reader with relation to dough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your clarification. I have edited my question.

Comment: @JamesK Thank you for your edit. I should not have put that preamble in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some great comments below the question, so I'm going to try to provide an answer that summarises some of that content.*

There is no general rule about when repeated words can be omitted. Learning to be comfortable with when omissions make sense is probably going to be a matter of experience.

But there is a lot of flexibility, even in formal written English, and "the shorter the better" is the general practice in English, so long as ambiguity is not introduced.

So any of the following are grammatical, but the first would be considered cumbersome and unnecessary.

> There were more students in class today than there were students in class yesterday.
>
> More students were in class today than were there yesterday.
>
> More students were in class today than yesterday.

One rule that *does* seem to apply (as far as I can see) is that when the verb changes significantly, you may need to stop omitting words if you want to avoid misunderstanding.

These two sentences (as @FumbleFingers pointed out) do not mean the same thing at all.

> I am making **more** effort and reading **more** grammar textbooks.
>
> I am making **more** effort and reading grammar textbooks.

There is no implied "more" with relation to grammar textbooks in the second sentence.

I suspect one of the better grammarians (than me) on this site will be able to explain exactly why. Perhaps a subject for a separate question!

*(Because unanswered questions make my brain hurt.)

Comment: Have made them full sentences.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.

Comment: Can you tell me whether your claim “the shorter the better also holds in formal writing (Can you give me any reference)? So, can we say that the sentence “*More students were in class today than were there yesterday*” is more appropriate for formal writing than the sentence “*More students were in class today than yesterday*”?

Comment: @Later: I don't think any style guide would actually *recommend* the longer form for your example there (in general, the maxim *less is more* applies just as much to formal communications as it does to poetic / literary and relaxed conversational contexts). But some people who aren't *used* to writing formal text tend to make the "mistake" of being unnaturally verbose / circumloquacious when operating outside their normal linguistic "comfort zone". Don't copy them.

Comment: @Later - FumbleFingers explained exactly why using fewer words is the right choice. So long as there is no ambiguity or confusion in your grammar, it is always a good idea to exclude words that don't need to be there. Excluding words doesn't mean 'use short sentences' necessarily, it means 'express yourself in the most concise and clear way possible'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment is very helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @fred2 Your comment is very helpful to me. Thanks.