# Examining some elliptical structures - Part II

Tags: grammar, pronouns, ellipsis, formal-language

After reading the comments and answer for [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202491/some-clarifications-are-needed-about-the-grammar-of-elliptical-structure), I have realized that the best (and/or maybe the only) way to master elliptical structure is seeing and examining more examples in this subject.

I have seen that we can have the following typical examples in elliptical structures:

> *I answered the question yesterday, and **him** <sub>answered the question</sub> today.*
>
> *She made him angry, not **him** <sub>made</sub> her <sub>angry</sub> .*

(Please note that in above examples the elided words are indicated with subscripts.)

But, I expected that the following must be correct:

> *I answered the question yesterday, and **he** <sub>answered the question</sub> today.*
>
> *She made him angry, not **he** <sub>made</sub> her <sub>angry</sub> .*

Can any one help me to answer the following?

1. Are the former typical examples correct? Why do we have such typical examples? Are English speakers free to use objective pronouns instead of subjective ones whenever they want?
2. If all of them are correct, which form is more appropriate for formal writing?

---

## Updated

For those who may claim that the above examples are absolutely incorrect I want to cite the following passage from Hudson’s article<sup>1</sup>(pages 61& 62):

*”In particular, pronouns often appear in their non-subject form when they are in the subject position of a gapped conjunct: He likes her, and her, him. Some speakers say they prefer the subject form in such cases (He likes her, and she, him), but we simply do not know for sure who actually uses which form in speech ... The main fact is that non-subject pronoun forms are far more acceptable in subject position when they precede a gap than in other situations.”*

1. Hudson, R. 1989. Gapping and grammatical relations. Journal of Linguistics 25, 57-94. One can read the article [here](http://dickhudson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/gapping.pdf).

Comment: Please note that my native language is very different from English and I am learning the basics of English, so please excuse me if I cannot convey the main idea of my question. Please also note that I am only interested in **formal English**, so please answer my question with respect to this fact.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you want to elide. ***I*** answered the question today, not ***him***.That is elided but it is not formal. Your others are not right. On what basis are you saying they are typical examples?

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your comment. I have updated my original post; I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: ***"He likes her, and her [or she], him." is 100% correct***. "Her" is a direct object of likes. It's fine. BUT: In "Mary [she] made him [John] angry." **make** is a causative verb, and **not him, her** does not work there. Mary made John angry, not Sheila.  And "I answered the question today, and **he did** yesterday." Or: "I answered the question today, not him." I hope you find this helpful. Leaving gaps is very complicated and I am not writing a book on it here. :)

Comment: John let Mary cut his hair, not Susie. John let Mary cut his hair, not her, him.=a no-go. Another causative example that would not work. It's best not to make comments "who claim the above examples are completely incorrect" when the examples are completely different than the quoted linguist's example.

Comment: @Lambie You have claimed that one cannot apply gapping for causative verbs; do you have any references for your claim? I have seen several articles about gapping and elliptical structures, but I have not found any rule preventing one from applying gapping for causative verbs. Also, I hope you do not expect that I ***have to*** use exactly the same examples as ones mentioned in some linguistic article, since I do not want to just learn those specific examples.

Comment: You ask: Are the former typical examples correct? There is nothing typical about them. (And by the way, typically, we say object pronouns and subject pronouns, not objective and subjective). Good luck with your endeavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two examples are wrong—and they are wrong for the reason you indicate:

> ✘  **Him** answered the question today.
>   ✘  **Him** made her angry.

In the elided phrases, it's the subjective form that's needed, not the objective form.

The so-called wrong versions may be *used* by some people in the elided phrases, but they are technically incorrect. And certainly incorrect in formal writing.

---

Over time, they may become more more acceptable than they are now—and to the point where most grammarians *wouldn't* correct them (as they would today).

For instance:

> "Who's at the door?"
>   "It's I!"

That is the technically correct answer to the question.

But:

> "Who's at the door?"
>   "It's me!"

While technically *incorrect*, this has become the standard reply. And, because it is used far more commonly now than the former, it has become, through idiomatic usage, acceptable. In fact, the technically *correct* version is so infrequently used, that it sounds awkward—and it's use would be questioned, even in some formal writing.

Speaking personally, *it's I* sounds strange even to me. Having said that, if I drop the contraction, turning it into *it is I*, then it sounds fine—albeit old fashioned (and, in fact, *it is me*, without the contraction, now becomes the more awkward of the two).

---

I don't think we're at the point where your first two examples would be left uncorrected by most grammarians. But, who knows how our usage will have evolved in the next fifty or a hundred years?

Comment: The first two examples are incorrect and the last two which are rewrites cannot be elided, really.

Comment: @Lambie The main issue in the question was the subjective versus the objective. But the elision itself is arguably correct, speaking stylistically. As from [this post](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch06/ch06_sec049.html) from *The Chicago Manual of Style*, "Jasper missed her and she him."

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for your perfect answer. You have given the complete answer to my questions; however, you may be interested in sharing your opinion on the quoted material in my updated original post.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for helping me. I think that for saying with certainty that something is *incorrect* it needs to give some reference. I see in your comment that you have stated some grammar rules which I cannot find in any grammar resources (I think those rules are not globally acceptable since it seems that Jason Bassford does not agree with you). Can you give me any reference or citation supporting such rules?

Comment: @Lambie Also, you stated that such structures are not appropriate for formal writing. However, some people, such as (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202491/some-clarifications-are-needed-about-the-grammar-of-elliptical-structure#comment393371_202872 ) and (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202491/some-clarifications-are-needed-about-the-grammar-of-elliptical-structure#comment393374_202872 ) have encouraged me to use more elliptical structures in formal writing as much as possible. Do you disagree with them?

Comment: @Later From the beginning, you seem reluctant to believe me, which can be seen in your comment re "those who may claim".There is only one person saying this and that person is me. For your information, Fred2's examples are not like the ones in your question: they are clearly examples of written English, not spoken English (like yours). Leaving out words in English is different in spoken English than in written English. That said, I cannot do anything but share what I know but only with those are interested.

Comment: @Lambie As I said, my native language is very different from English, so please excuse me if I have disturbed you (I expected that no one would judge me from my words in a language which is not my native one). I appreciate any help from any one. I only wanted to provide a reference for my examples for the people who may have doubts about them. However, I thank you again: **Thank you for your helps**.

Comment: @Lambie Since my native language is *”very different from English”*, I may not express my attitude well.

Comment: @Lambie I did not mean Fred2’s examples. I asked them about the importance of elliptical structures in formal writing, and then they have encouraged me to use them as much as possible (Please see the comments I have linked for you). However, I am one of those who are interested in your comments; they have helped me very much.

Comment: @Later "Also, you stated that such structures are not appropriate for formal writing." The ones you try to give in your examples are not good for formal writing. Fred2's examples are fine in formal writing. I'm done here.

Comment: There's no such thing as *technically incorrect, but sanctioned by usage* – not in English, or any one language used by people, simply because there's no such thing as a higher authority on a language; the only authority is people who speak it. Anyhow, both *it's me* and *it is I* are **grammatical** responses in that context. The former belongs to **neutral / informal style, and the latter to very formal style**. I suggest you leave out the "technically (in)correct" descriptors in general. They are misleading, especially when you characterize completely unremarkable utterances as "incorrect".

Comment: @userr2684291 Thank you for your comment.