# Examining some elliptical structures - Part IV

Tags: grammar, ellipsis, formal-language

After reading the comments and answer for [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202491/some-clarifications-are-needed-about-the-grammar-of-elliptical-structure), I have realized that the best (and/or maybe the only) way to master elliptical structure is seeing and examining more examples in this subject.

I have read somewhere that in the following typical examples the infinitival *to* must be retained and such examples without it are grammatically incorrect:

> *He wants to answer the question, and she wants **to** <sub>answer the question</sub> as well.*
>
> *I like to study math, and you like **to** <sub>study math</sub> as well.*

(Please note that the elided words are indicated with subscripts.)

But, I have seen the following typical examples without the infinitival *to*:

> *He tried to go, and she tried <sub>to go</sub> as well.*
>
> *I asked you to help, but you refused <sub>to help</sub> .*

Can any one explain to me whether I should elide the infinitival *to* in such elliptical structures or not (in formal writing)?

Comment: Please note that my native language is very different from English and I am learning the basics of English, so please excuse me if I cannot convey the main idea of my question. Please also note that I am only interested in **formal English**, so please answer my question with respect to this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try* and *refuse* can be transitive or intransitive. "He tried" and "you refused" are complete sentences, even though they have no objects.

It's likely that in your second set of example sentences there's actually no ellipsis.  That is, it's not "I asked you to help, but you refused <sub>to help</sub>," it's simply "I asked you to help, but you refused."

On the other hand, *like* is always transitive. "You like" is not a complete sentence. *Want* is sometimes intransitive, but this use is not nearly as common as the transitive use, and it has a slightly different meaning. "She wants" is a complete sentence, but it might mean *she is destitute* or *she has some unspecified lack*.

> **want**
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> 1 : to be needy or destitute
>
> 2 : to have or feel need
> // never *wants* for friends
>
> 3 : to be necessary or needed
>
> 4 : to desire to come, go, or be
> // the cat *wants* in
> // *wants* out of the deal
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want

So, if you drop the infinitive *to*, it is not clear that there's an ellipsis; it will appear as if you're trying to use the verb intransitively. Only some verbs can be used intransitively, and for others, the intransitive use has a different meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. So according to your answer, the sentence *”I asked you to help, but you refused to”* can be grammatically correct, right?

Comment: Yes, @Later, that would be fine.