# Examining some elliptical structures - Part V

Tags: grammar, ellipsis, formal-language

After reading the comments and answer for [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202491/some-clarifications-are-needed-about-the-grammar-of-elliptical-structure), I have realized that the best (and/or maybe the only) way to master elliptical structure is seeing and examining more examples in this subject.

I have seen that in some elliptical sentences the elided material can precede its antecedent, for example

> *The student who wanted to answer the question did <sub>answer the question</sub> .*
>
> *The student who wanted to <sub>answer the question</sub> did answer the question .*

(Please note that the elided words are indicated with subscripts.)

Can any one tell me whether such a form (i.e., letting the ellipsis precede its antecedent) is appropriate for formal writing? If so, under what circumstances can one apply it in elliptical structures?

Comment: Please note that my native language is very different from English and I am learning the basics of English, so please excuse me if I cannot convey the main idea of my question. Please also note that I am only interested in **formal English**, so please answer my question with respect to this fact.

Comment: I wonder how you define formal english. According to a specific english as a foreign language test? I've been a technical writer for 20 years, so I produce "formal documents", but I suspect more and more that the idea of "formal *english* " itself is artificial...

Comment: @sesquipedalias You mean that the term “*formal English*” is incorrect?

Comment: @Later Please note that the purpose of comments is not to provide updates to your post (or, in your case, repeated information).

Comment: @userr2684291 I think that comment should not be considered as repeated information for the one who would meet this post for the first time, right?

Comment: @Later no, I just wonder whether it's not a much more intuitive, hand-waivy concept that one might think...

Comment: @sesquipedalias Thank you for your clarification; I misunderstood your previous comment.

Comment: I would only elide something that was previously mentioned. Eliding something to only mention it later is awkward—because there is a period of confusion that exists until the latter part of the sentence is read. (In other words, I don't like the second version of the example sentence.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you very much for your comment.